# How to install mod_fastcgi.so into apache

Tags: fastcgi, trac, apache-2.2

How do I get the mod_fastcgi.so module and load it into apache2? I need it for a deployment of trac. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yum whatprovides mod_fastcgi.so # will tell you what package contains mod_fastcgi.so 
yum install the_package
```

Comment: Actually I'm using Ubuntu 10.4, I probably should I have mentioned that.

Comment: apt-cache search fastcgi

Comment: thanks. I think I found it. I'm going to install the 'libapache2-mod-fcgid' package.